# Configuring Search in SharePoint 2019 farm

Tags: search, sharepoint-search, 2019, search-configuration

This is 2019 SharePoint farm.

We have two Application with search servers and two web front end servers with distributed cache servers.

I am planning to configure search in the farm, but I am not sure how the search topology will be. Can someone help me on this?

The topology will be automatically configured or we can do it manually?

Answer (score 0):

You can always manually edit the topology with powershell.  As far as the topology goes, it really depends on what you are trying to achieve.  If you want HA then both search servers will need to have all the search rolls running on them.  If you are looking for speed then you would divide up the the rolls between the two servers.